# how to reduce speed in image and text on the fraction-slider?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using fraction-slider.

In default fraction-slider my requirement is to reduce speed in image and text on the fraction-slide.

```
// defaults & options
    var options = $.extend({
            'slideTransition' : 'none', // default slide transition
            'slideTransitionSpeed' : 2000, // default slide transition
            'slideEndAnimation' : true, // if set true, objects will transition out at slide end (before the slideTransition is called)
            'position' : '0,0', // default position | should never be used
            'transitionIn' : 'left', // default in - transition
            'transitionOut' : 'left', // default out - transition
            'fullWidth' : false, // transition over the full width of the window
            'delay' : 0, // default delay for elements
            'timeout' : 2000, // default timeout before switching slides
            'speedIn' : 2500, // default in - transition speed
            'speedOut' : 1000, // default out - transition speed
            'easeIn' : 'easeOutExpo', // default easing in
            'easeOut' : 'easeOutCubic', // default easing out

            'controls' : false, // controls on/off
            'pager' : false, // controls on/off
            'autoChange' : true, // auto change slides
            'pauseOnHover' : false, // Pauses slider on hover (current step will still be completed)

            'backgroundAnimation' : false, // background animation
            'backgroundElement' : null, // element to animate | default fractionSlider element
            'backgroundX' : 500, // default x distance
            'backgroundY' : 500, // default y distance
            'backgroundSpeed' : 2500, // default background animation speed
            'backgroundEase' : 'easeOutCubic', // default background animation easing

            'responsive' : false, // activates the responsive slider
            'increase' : false, // if set, slider is allowed to get bigger than basic dimensions
            'dimensions' : '', // set basic dimension (width,height in px) for the responisve slider - the plugin with position elements with data-position relative to this dimensions (please see the documentation for more info),

            'startCallback' : null,
            'startNextSlideCallback' : null,
            'stopCallback' : null,
            'pauseCallback' : null,
            'resumeCallback' : null,
            'nextSlideCallback' : null,
            'prevSlideCallback' : null,
            'pagerCallback' : null
        }, option);
```

Where should I go to change the value in this default script?

Comment: You should try and figure out the problem yourself, before blindly copying and posting code here. We appreciate people who put in more effort than Ctrl-C and Ctrl-V

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this not self explanatory?

```
'timeout' : 2000, // default timeout before switching slides
```

Comment: thank's dude. it's working, in past, i have changed this all things slideTransitionSpeed' : 400,
                'backgroundSpeed' : 400,
                'timeout' : 400 in simultaneously. now rectified with only changing the timout. thank's again